# POST query special syntax

Tags: rest, post

For example, I need to publish the entity and I remember using a very specific endpoint for this: POST /projects/{id}:publish.
Cannot find the information about this kind of using of POST requests (with a semicolon). Is this the right approach?

Answer (score 0):

[RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-A)

```
pchar         = unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / ":" / "@"
```

In other words, it's fine.

Note that, as far as *general purpose* HTTP components are concerned, `/projects/12345:publish` and `/projects/12345` are *different* resources.  Here, that might actually be an advantage - but you should be certain that you understand the implications (see [RFC 9111](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9111.html)).